# Amend VBA code required to extract email from outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using below code to extract the data from outlook but the code is extracting only one month data and its clearing all the data from column D.

I don't want the data to be cleared from column D

```
Option Explicit
' Got this code from http://superuser.com/questions/816289/exporting-attachment-file-name-email-metadata-from-outlook-to-excel
Sub GetMailInfo()
    
    Dim results()   As String
    
    ' get contacts
    results = ExportEmails(True)
    
    ' paste onto worksheet
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2))).Value = results
    
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub

Function ExportEmails(Optional headerRow As Boolean = False) As String()
    
    Dim objOutlook  As Object        ' Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Object        ' Outlook.Namespace
    Dim strFolderName As Object
    Dim objMailbox  As Object
    Dim objFolder   As Object
    Dim mailFolderItems As Object        ' Outlook.items
    Dim folderItem  As Object
    Dim msg         As Object        ' Outlook.MailItem
    Dim tempString() As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim numRows     As Long
    Dim startRow    As Long
    Dim jAttach     As Long        ' counter for attachments
    Dim debugMsg    As Integer
    
    ' select output results worksheet and clear previous results
    Sheets("Outlook Results").Select
    Sheets("Outlook Results").Cells.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'MsgBox objOutlook, vbOKOnly 'for debugging
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'MsgBox objNamespace, vbOKOnly 'for debugging
    'Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'MsgBox objInbox, vbOKOnly 'for debugging
    Set strFolderName = objNamespace.PickFolder
    Set mailFolderItems = strFolderName.Items
    mailFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", FALSE
    
    ' if calling procedure wants header row
    If headerRow Then
        startRow = 1
    Else
        startRow = 0
    End If
    
    numRows = mailFolderItems.Count
    
    ' resize array
    ReDim tempString(1 To (numRows + startRow), 1 To 100)
    mailFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", FALSE
    ' loop through folder items
    For i = 1 To numRows
        Set folderItem = mailFolderItems.Item(i)
        
        If IsMail(folderItem) Then
            Set msg = folderItem
        End If
        
        With msg
            tempString(i + startRow, 1) = .SenderName
            tempString(i + startRow, 2) = .ReceivedTime
            tempString(i + startRow, 3) = .Subject
            'tempString(i + startRow, 4) = Left$(.Body, 200)  ' throws error without limit
            'tempString(i + startRow, 5) = .SenderEmailAddress
            'tempString(i + startRow, 6) = .SentOn
            
        End With
        
        ' adding file attachment names where they exist - added by JP
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 50 Then
            
            For jAttach = 1 To msg.Attachments.Count
                tempString(i + startRow, 39 + jAttach) = msg.Attachments.Item(jAttach).DisplayName
            Next jAttach
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    ' first row of array should be header values
    If headerRow Then
        
        tempString(1, 1) = "SenderName"
        tempString(1, 2) = "ReceivedTime"
        tempString(1, 3) = "subject"
        'tempString(1, 4) = "Body"
        'tempString(1, 5) = "SenderEmailAddress"
        'tempString(1, 6) = "SentOn"
    End If
    
    ExportEmails = tempString
    
    ' apply pane freeze and filtering
    
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = TRUE
    Rows("1:1").Select    
    'Selection.AutoFilter 
End Function
Function IsMail(itm As Object) As Boolean
    IsMail = (TypeName(itm) = "MailItem")
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

> I don't want the data to be cleared from column D

In the code you may find the following line of code which causes that:

```
Sheets("Outlook Results").Cells.ClearContents
```

> but the code is extracting only one month data

The code iterates over all items in the folder. It seems Outlook caches the data for a month only.

---

Also pay attention to the duplicated code lines:

```
Set mailFolderItems = strFolderName.Items
mailFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", FALSE
```

And later in the code you are sorting the same collection anew:

```
mailFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", FALSE
```

Also I've noticed that Outlook shortcuts are used in the code:

```
 With msg
            tempString(i + startRow, 1) = .SenderName
            tempString(i + startRow, 2) = .ReceivedTime
            tempString(i + startRow, 3) = .Subject
```

If the code is run from Excel you need to declare the fully qualified names.

Comment: HI Eugene, I tried to disable the code Sheets("Outlook Results").Cells.ClearContents but still it clears all the contents in the sheet

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and address comments listed in my post?